# convert the following json to csv using python

Tags: python, json, csv

```
{"a":"1","b":"1","c":"1"}
{"a":"2","b":"2","c":"2"}
{"a":"3","b":"3","c":"3"}
{"a":"4","b":"4","c":"4"}
```

I have tried the following code but it gives error:-

```
from nltk.twitter import Twitter
from nltk.twitter.util import json2csv

with open('C:/Users/Archit/Desktop/raw_tweets.json', 'r') as infile:
# Variable for building our JSON block
json_block = []

for line in infile:

    # Add the line to our JSON block
    json_block.append(line)

    # Check whether we closed our JSON block
    if line.startswith('{'):

        # Do something with the JSON dictionary
        json2csv(json_block, 'tweets.csv', ['id','text','created_at','in_reply_to_user_id','in_reply_to_screen_name','in_reply_to_status_id','user.id','user.screen_name','user.name','user.location','user.friends_count','user.followers_count','source'])

        # Start a new block
        json_block = []
```

Error:

File "C:\Python34\lib\json\decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Where are you getting that `json2csv` function?

Comment: sorry didnt get what u said ?

Comment: Sorry, I'll be a bit more explicit. You're using the `json2csv` function, but that is not defined anywhere. Are you importing it from somewhere? When I run your code, I get `NameError: name 'json2csv' is not defined`.

Comment: yep ... from nltk.twitter.util import json2csv

Comment: That is relevant information and should be included in your question.

Comment: @ArchitGarg, what is your expected output for example input?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv, json

data = []

with open('C:\Users\Shahriar\Desktop\T.txt') as data_file:    
    for line in data_file:
        data.append(json.loads(line))


keys = data[0].keys()

with open('data.csv', 'wb') as csvF:
    csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(csvF, fieldnames=keys)
    csvWriter.writeheader()
    for d in data:
        csvWriter.writerow(d)
```

Output:

```
a,c,b
1,1,1
2,2,2
3,3,3
4,4,4
```

Answer (score 1):

This is way too late but I also stumbled upon some errors today. I figured that you actually have to import from nltk.twitter.common instead of util. Hope this helps others who stumbled upon this thread

Answer (score 0):

```
# Read json 
filename = 'C:/Users/Archit/Desktop/raw_tweets.json'
lines = [line.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace(":", ",") for line in open(filename)]

# Write csv
with open('out.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
   for line in lines:
      csv_file.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Comment: raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Archit\Desktop\csv_conv.py", line 35, in <module>
    csv_file.write("%s\n" % line)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Comment: `"a","1","b","1","c","1"` is this your output csv?

Comment: @ArchitGarg thank you, it was missing the opening mode

Comment: @AerofoilKite Yes. The OP didn't specify the output format. So, it is safer to to include the quotes in case the elements have commas, like "0", "0,5", "1"...